# How to remove square brackets from a dictionary output and replace with curly brackets?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am a newbie to Swift so kindly excuse me if this question sounds too silly.
I am trying to create a JSON object from a dictionary Array output which must have Curly Brackets("{}") after each entity rather than Square brackets ("[]"). My Code is given below.

```
import UIKit

var locations = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

var myLocations = ["pqr","xyz"]

myLocations.forEach {_ in 
    var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
    dictionary["string1"] = "hello"
    dictionary["string2"] = "world"
    locations.append(dictionary)

}
print(locations)
```

The output to this is:- **[["string2": "world", "string1": "hello"], ["string2": "world", "string1": "hello"]]\n**

However I require it as:- **[{"string2": "world", "string1": "hello"}, {"string2": "world", "string1": "hello"}]\n**

I know one way of doing this is by using filter Arrays but I suspect there could be an easier way to this which I am not able to find after searching through various documentations on Swift. Could you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want JSON? Then you can use `NSJSONSerialization`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried this and it appears to be working. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is

```
[["string2": "world", "string1": "hello"], ["string2": "world", "string1": "hello"]]
```

because this is a Swift array of Swift dictionaries.

To convert this object to JSON, do not parse and replace the characters yourself, use NSJSONSerialization instead:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(locations, options: [])
    if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        print(jsonString)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Prints:

> [{"string2":"world","string1":"hello"},{"string2":"world","string1":"hello"}]

We use `dataWithJSONObject` to convert your Swift object to JSON *data*, then we use `String(data:, encoding:)` to convert this JSON data to a JSON *string*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just tried this and it worked.:)

Comment: when i put it int a string, it adds "/" before ""

Comment: Error: Cannot find 'locations' in scope